# How to configure lighttpd with CGI and JSON?

Tags: json, rest, webserver, cgi, lighttpd

I want to use lighttpd server with mod_cgi module.

1. How can I write a CGI script to parse POST JSON requests and send out JSON response back for GET requests?
2. What needs to be configured in lighthttpd server so that I can have a restful service? I don't see JSON mime type in the conf file.
3. Is there a JSON parser or module that I can include Lighttpd web server?

Can you give me any directions?